# Localized or Customized Column Names in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, where I've abstracted the SQL column names. The first table has an "original" column name and a "header" name. The second table uses the "original" column name.

```
--Columns table
ColumnName          HeaderName
StandardColumn_1    balance
StandardColumn_2    FName
StandardColumn_3    LName       
StandardColumn_4    Age

--Records table
StandardColumn_1    StandardColumn_2      StandardColumn_3
Value1              Value2                Value3
```

Now, I have to write a query using the "header" name in C#. How can I query the records table using the "header" name?

e.g. `string balance = "StandardColumn_1";`, but I need to get the values dynamically from the columns table.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to just query the first table, and store it in a `Dictionary` to be used for querying the second table.

```
 Dictionary<string, string> columnMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...))
 using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT HeaderName, ColumnName FROM Columns"))
 using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
 {
     while (dr.Read()) 
     {
        columnMap.Add(dr.GetString(0), dr.GetString(1));
     }
 }
```

Now, you have a map from `HeaderName` to `ColumnName` that you can use for building your SQL query. It'd be common practice to cache this map, since the header names are usually done through some sort of setup process and don't change often.

If your "header" names are unique enough, then a simple replace will do the trick:

```
 const string originalSql = "SELECT Balance FROM Records WHERE Age = 23";
 string convertedSql = originalSql;
 foreach (var kvp in columnMap) 
 {
       convertedSql = convertedSql.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
 }
```

If they're not guaranteed unique substrings (eg., you could have "Name" and "FName"), then you'll probably need to use a regular expression to replace instead.

Comment: Hi mark,the values are not replacing I am getting error that column name balance and age not found

Comment: @AmolNaik - note that string.Replace is a case-sensitive comparison so the casing must match in the "Columns" table

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to accomplish is a bit of a mystery to me, but I'll try to answer anyway. I will assume that `Column Name` is a sequence of `StandardColumn_i` strings, where `i >= 1`, and that you would like to assign consecutive "standard columns" to a knows set of strings. One way to do this is to create a dictionary and populate it in a loop.

Firstly, we create an array of all header names and a standard prefix.

```
string[] headers = new[] { "balance", "FName", "LName", "Age" };
string prefix = "StandardColumn_";
```

Then we create a new `Dictionary` object and fill it with "standard columns" inside a loop:

```
Dictionary<string, string> columnDict = new Dictionary<string, string>
for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
{
    columnDict.Add(headers[i], prefix + (i + 1));
}
```

You can now retrieve column names with an indexer, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(dict["FName"]); // prints 'StandardColumn_2'
```